# Why didn't Voldemort directly go back to Death Eater headquarters?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

After his killing curse rebounded and destroyed his body, Voldemort was scared because he turned into a really weak spirit, and decided to escape.

Why didn't he just escape towards his current Death Eater headquarters? There he can show his followers that he's still alive so they won't panic and help him get a new body ASAP.

Instead he escapes to Albania, alone and far from him followers, *which still required him to cross England in his vulnerable state anyway*. So equally dangerous but much more idiotic.

Comment: The loyalties of Death Eaters are not completely secure, now that Voldemort himself is powerless. There's no guarantee that they would help to revive him instead of finishing him off and turning up at the ministry like "I killed Voldemort, I'm a good guy now".

Comment: I'd have to dig out my copy of the books to confirm it, but IIRC, after his resurrection, he specifically calls out the Death Eaters for abandoning him, with the exception of Wormtail. So I think, in conjunction with what AJFaraday mentioned above, he was testing to see if they'd still (literally) follow him.

Comment: @AJFaraday I don't get why Voldy complains nobody came to help him when he didn't trust anyone enough to let them do it anyway. It's his fault, not his followers'. Some of them tried but failed to find him (Bellatrix)

Comment: Because it's easy to call out your (returned) followers *after* you've managed to pull yourself together without their help.

Comment: Not only was he broken, but the whole 'dark side' was weakened. Soon after, much of his followers either fled, gave up or were captured. He did he best he could.

Comment: And the Ministry . . . without Voldemort, the Death Eaters probably wouldn't stand a chance.